# Evaluate AngularJS expression within Material Design Lite's mdl-menu

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

I am building a tiny single-page-application using Angular for the functionality and mdl for the design. I wanted to have a dropdown select box and since mdl doesn't provide this out of the box I built one using mdl-menu. The problem is now that Angular seems to have troubles evaluating expressions I put inside this menu, maybe because the menu is only opened when you click the button? I tried using expressions within the list items and this gives the expression output but also the original expression, which I obviously don't want. I also tried to ng-repeat the list items and then they just don't show up.

```
<button id="demo-menu-lower-left"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    for="demo-menu-lower-left">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">{{5+5}}</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

[Result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0n0h.png) (Look at the evaluation in the top left, but the original expression is the actual "clickable" action)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDL's javascript (denoted by the `mdl-js` CSS classes) will probably fool around with the HTML before Angular can do anything, eventually creating HTML that gives strange results when 'parsed' by Angular. It would be best to ensure your HTML gets processed in a strict order: Angular first, MDL second.

If you need to work with the HTML after the initial loading and rendering of the page, it would help to inspect the HTML in the browser instead of relying on the source HTML. Any javascript code (including Angular) will have to work with this and not the HTML represented by the source.